# Android Parser XML Data from .net webservice USING KSOAP2

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am working on a Android application that receives response from .Net Webservice as XML.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><NewDataSet>
<Table>
<Area> Area A </Area>
<code>100000</code>
</Table>
<Table>
<Area>Area B </Area>
<code>100001</code>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

I need to parse this Xml into listview in next activity.

Can someone please guide me how to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html. check the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, for example, create a class `ListViewElement` and store each data in this class. When you got every `ListViewElement`, just store each of them in an `ArrayList`. Finally, you just have to write an [ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) to display your data.